# JavaScript Array push() method use to the id as the index value?

Tags: javascript

I want to use id as the index value and then generate a new array.
What better way do you have?

**This is the result I want**

```
Arr:Array[2]
3:"a"
8:"b"
```

**Before processing**

```
Arr:Array[2]
0:"a"
1:"b"
```

**My code**

```js
var data = [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'b',
  }
]
var arr = []
const p = data.map(item => {
  arr[item.id].push(item.name)
})
console.log(p)
```

Comment: Just change it to `arr[item.id] = item.name` and log `arr` instead of `p`. But, why do you need this? An object or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) seems like a better structure for this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `reduce`, initialised with an empty array, set each index with `id`, and each value with `name`:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'b',
  }
]

console.log(data.reduce((a, {id, name}) => (a[id] = name, a), []))
```

> NOTE, you cannot have an array without indexes between values. Javascript will automatically fill these with `undefined`

If this doesn't fit your needs, then the only other option is to use an object <sup>(or a map but that's more complicated :P)</sup>, which can still act like an array in a sense:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 3,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: 'b',
  }
]

const obj = data.reduce((a, {id, name}) => (a[id] = name, a), {})

console.log(obj)
console.log(obj[3]) // a
console.log(obj[8]) // b
```